# Answer to Who Issued your Visa?

Tags: visas, usa

I am a prospective graduate student. I have been issued US visa. And I'm applying to other Universities. In the application it asks: Who Issued your Visa? The question is asked in an admission application.

What should be the answer? The University or the embassy location from where it is issued?

[image]

Comment: What type of visa is it? Are you changing universities after having studied in one or is it the first year you would study in the US?

Comment: F1 visa. I did not go there yet.

Comment: If I get it correctly : You have been issued a F1 visa sponsored by an university which accepted you, now you want to not enroll with that university and enroll elsewhere?

Comment: This is a bit confusing.  Perhaps they want the "issuing post name" shown on the visa, but I can't imagine why.  The visa is certainly not issued by the educational institution, so if that's the answer they want they should be asking the question differently. (Institutions issue I-20 and DS-2019 forms, but these are not visas.)  So I wonder whether you are paraphrasing the question or omitting some context that may have been established by previous questions.  Can you post an image of the application that shows the question and, if relevant, the preceding questions?

Comment: It is unclear. I think the OP is facing a university application of some kind.

Comment: edited and added the picture. It's an university application.

Comment: I closed and re-opened so there are no close votes on it anymore.

Comment: I suspect ‘who issued your visa’ is the university, and the ‘issued in city’ is the location where it was issued. Ir might help if you uploaded a photo of the visa with personal data blanked out

Comment: @Traveller universities simply do not issue visas.  If you're right, then answers might indicate, for example, that the University of Hawaii issued the visa in Hyderabad, India.  It doesn't make sense.  Xenon Kfr: can you ask the university what the question means?  They surely don't care about the name of the consular officer, they ask elsewhere for the location, and they already know that the issuing agency is the US Department of State.  It seems like a pointless question.  What types of visas are available in the pick list for the second question?

Comment: @phoog I agree, which is why I only posted a comment. I searched for images of F1 visas and some do seem to include the university name eg https://www.ecosia.org/images?q=F1%20visa%20images#id=E5B59FFF55319E57E50559E2E8CA54834CFB839C

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only valid answer to that question as phrased is the US government service which issued the visa, which in the vast majority of cases would be “US embassy in X” or “US consulate in Y”.

This is clearly redundant with the next question “Issued in city”, but anything else would be factually incorrect.

You may want to contact them to check that this is indeed what they are asking for, but there is no other possible interpretation of the question as it is written.

PS: actually there could be another interpretation which would be the name of the officer who issued the visa, but I’m not sure that info is actually given, and I seriously doubt it could be of any use.